# How to execute extreme long command with C++?

Tags: c++, windows, cmd, cygwin

I am trying to execute quite long external command (curl with long parameters) in my C++ program.

Works fine on Linux, but Windows (under Cygwin) always shows "System cannot execute specified program" if "cmd" is longer than 127 chars.

Linux accepts with same code almost unlimited size.
Tried changing size of buffer, no change.

Used this code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

std::string exec(char* cmd) {
    FILE* pipe = _popen(cmd, "r");
    if (!pipe) 
        return "ERROR";

    char buffer[128];
    std::string result = "";
    while(!feof(pipe)) {
        if(fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
            result += buffer;
    }
    _pclose(pipe);
    return result;
}
```

Is that Windows specific limitation, or is possible somehow to extend the cmd buffer?

Added how is created char* which I am trying to send:

```
   string message="This is message to send.";
   std::string send="";
   std::string curl_header="curl -s -F \"token=aE71iieVt8G1RWdJb59qmAa3hbxxxx\" -F \"user=uPKYQyNgGURbH1g56nBnjn9jNsxxxxx\" -F \"message=";
   send.append(curl_header);
   send.append(message);
   send.append("\" https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json");
   cout << "\n";
   cout << "FULL STRING WITH PARAMS TO EXECUTE:";
   std::cout << send << '\n';
   char *cstr = new char[send.length() + 1];
   strcpy(cstr, send.c_str());
   cout << "FULL CHAR ARRAY WITH PARAMS TO EXECUTE:";
   std::cout << cstr << '\n';//this returns correct string, even longer than 127 chars
   cout << exec(cstr);// this returns error, same with system() if cstr is longer than 127 chars
    delete [] cstr;
```

Comment: I'm not sure, can you change size of buffer in your code to higher and try running that.

Comment: I suggest you print the value of [`errno`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/errno) using `strerror` after the `_popen` call fails.  The [documentation for `_popen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b.aspx) says that `errno` will be set.

Comment: Not sure if I understood properly, but after adding line "strerror(errno)", program returns "No error" statement. I guess, that  _popen is not failing, added some cout`s around code and found that while() loop runs one if buffer is set to 256, but not adding any chars to "result".

@user3130843 - Changing buffer variable does not change anything - exec() still accepts 127 chars only.

Comment: Try making the first part of the command `echo curl` so as to see what command line Windows is actually seeing.  If the problem isn't obvious, try running that command line manually and see whether or not it works.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I have tried this with no luck. First thought that there is problem with some slashes/backslashes. So I have used cout << send and string looks like it should. Also if I shorten string "message" and last send.append() string all to be 127 o less chars, I am ccorrectly getting correct curl syntax error.

Comment: So what happens if you use `echo curl` ?  You still get "System cannot execute specified program"?  Since there's no problem if you use a constant string, I think the string must be corrupt somehow, even if the problem isn't obvious.  Try printing it character by character (i.e., so the output is "char 1=c char 2=u " and so on).  Also, the code you've shown doesn't define `send` ; could you edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Modified as complete example.
If I cout "send" string or "cstr" char* everything prints correctly, even when it is longer than 127 chars. After if I exec() it, get "System cannot execute specified program". You can replace curl (or use any other command) parameters in string with random characters and it still occurs when final string "send" is longer than 127, no matter what characters are inside.
As I wrote in OP, this is somehow platform problem, as this code works without changes on Linux perfectly. So I guess that there is nothing wrong with string contents.

Comment: Your code works perfectly when built with Visual Studio 2010.  What compiler are you using?  (Actually I had to change string to std::string and cout to std::cout to make it compile, but once that was done it worked.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thanks god if thats true! I am using Code::Blocks (CB) on both Windows and Linux as its platform independent and most time compiling for Linux. On Windows I have standart Cygwin GCC compiler, maybe thats the problem. I will install VS 2010 and try it again, found out that CB has support for VS compiler.

Comment: Cygwin has its own libraries, process management in particular is very different from Windows because it has to emulate fork().

Comment: On many systems, the command line limit includes all the environment variables.  So a limit of 4k with 3k env var, would leave 1k for the command line.  This page looks helpful http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/

Comment: @HarryJohnston On VS I have same problem. But at least found out whats causing this. Problem is in cmd.exe itself as its not accepting over 127 chars with curl command.Strange that with other commands it accepts much more. So it seems that its issue with curl.exe. I "just" have to find out why...

Comment: Under Cygwin you said you were having problems with all command lines, not just with curl.  If moving to VS makes other commands work, but not curl, then I would guess that this is indeed a Cygwin issue, and the problem now is that your version of curl is also running under Cygwin.  I suggest you investigate whether there are any non-Cygwin-based ports of curl available for Windows, or perhaps curl has the ability to read its parameters from a file, or from standard input?

Comment: @HarryJohnston It is definitely older curl bug.Curl binary in cygwin path was older version and it returned error,same error with some other tools.Tried standalone latest binary and it works fine with long strings from standart input.While posted I was calling external binaries from cygwin path,now I was able to call standalone binar without cygwin.Didnt suspected curl to be buggy,as error was returned in windows language and curl/cygwin is not localized.
So finally it is not CygwinGCC compiler problem,compiled it with and shipped to another PC with standalone curl binary and works fine at all

Comment: That doesn't explain why long commands beginning `echo curl` failed.  But never mind.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using system?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char** args){

if(argc<2){
    system("run run run run run run run run run run runr urn runrunrunru unr unrunr urn run runr unr urn run runrun runr unr urnrun runr urnurnrunrunrunrunrunrurn urnurnunrunrunrunrunrunrn u unru ru runr ur urn ru run rururnunrunrunr");
}else{
    printf("argc: %d",argc);
}
system("pause");
}
```

This seems to work fine to me. The program is named run, so it runs itself with that huge argument and then prints out the number of arguments it sees.  Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: Well this works in my case same as exec() - works fine if cmd string is written into system() directly.
But I am executing dynamically created char* and this doesnt work anymore. My char* is created by append function an stored in string and finally converted to char*.

Comment: But at the end of creating the char*, as long as it is a single char* that you pass to system, shouldn't it work?

Comment: Are you trying to stream data to an application? If so, use the stdin and stdout streams. As far as arguments/piping goes that is just meant to be run once with fixed parameters.

Comment: No. I am using Pushover API for sending messages online from local data files.  Here is my code for creating message and sending it:
    std::string curl_header="curl -s -F \"token=aE71iieVt8G1RWdJb59qmAa3hbxxxx\" -F \"user=uPKYQyNgGURbH1g56nBnjn9jNsxxxxx\" -F \"message=";
    send.append(curl_hlavicka);
    send.append(message);
    send.append("\" https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json");
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "STRING K ODESLANI:";
    std::cout << send << '\n';
    char *cstr = new char[send.length() + 1];
    strcpy(cstr, send.c_str());
    cout << exec(cstr);
    delete [] cstr;